# assets:precompile throws error: undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I've just started maintaining someone else's code base and I'm having trouble getting it to run locally in a production environment.  The error itself arises when precompiling the stylesheets.

It's a Rails 3.2.6 app running on Ruby 1.9.2. I noticed that in the output below, the gemset being used it global, which is odd because when I run

rvm gemset list

it indicates that the project's gemset is being used.  I'm not sure if this is a cause of my problem of if it's unrelated.

I'm not really sure what to do to fix this.  Any suggestions?

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:47:in `compile_path?'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:22:in `block in compile'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@challenge/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Are you using any CSS pre-processors or coffeescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your *environments/production.rb* make sure your `config.assets.precompile` is an Array and not set to `true`. Example from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

Comment: Aha!  Yep.  That was it.  Thank you!